Tanstack Data Table keeps resetting pagination
I have a table from @tanstack/react-table I want to implement pagination. I've the below so far and when I click next page it adds 1 to the pageIndex, but then immediately resets it back to 0.
CODE
"use client";

import { memo, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

import {
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";

import PaginationFooter from "./pagination-footer";

import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/client";

function DataTable({ columns }) {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 15,
  });

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    pageCount: Math.ceil(count / pagination.pageSize),
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    state: {
      rowSelection,
      pagination,
    },
  });

  const supabase = createClient();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const from = pagination.pageIndex * pagination.pageSize;
      const { data, count, error } = await supabase
        .from("contacts")
        .select("*", { count: "exact" })
        .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
        .range(from, from + pagination.pageSize - 1);

      if (error) {
        return;
      } else {
        setCount(count);
        setData(data);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [pagination.pageIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedRows = table.getSelectedRowModel().rows.map((row) => row.original);
    console.log(selectedRows);
  }, [rowSelection]);

  if (!mounted) return null;

  return (
    <div className="h-full flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-x-auto">
      <div className="flex-grow overflow-x-auto min-h-0">
        {...table}
      </div>
      <div className="select-none bg-background">
        <PaginationFooter table={table} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(DataTable);


I had to add manualPagination for this to work.
const table = useReactTable({
  data,
  columns,
  getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
  pageCount: Math.ceil(count / pagination.pageSize),
  onPaginationChange: setPagination,
  getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  manualPagination: true, // added
  state: {
    rowSelection,
    pagination,
  },
});


To manage pagination values in @tanstack/react-table, you have to be using setters and getters.
Start with an InitialState object with preferred values, then use getters and setters for managing it through the code.
So your code will be like this for the pagination
const { getState, setPageSize } = table;

// Destructure pageIndex and pageSize from the table's state
const { pageIndex, pageSize } = getState();

// Handler function to update the page size
const pageSizeHandler = (n: number) => {
  setPageSize(n);
};


I believe this is for custom implementation. Not the default as I’m using above.
